# Add pattern to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these two plots and I wanted to add patterns (or something) so that color is not the only distinguishing factor. Whatever pattern used in the plots has to be shown in the legend as well. How can I do that?
Here is my sample data and plot code.

```
Data <- data.frame(Label=c("BB","BB","BB","BB","WZ", "WZ","WZ", "WZ"), Direction=c("EB", "WB", "EB", "WB", "EB", "WB", "EB", "WB"), Delay=c(225, 137, 419, 265, 124, 234, 256, 256) )
Data$Label <- as.factor(Data$Label)

ggplot(Data,aes(x=Direction, y=(Delay), fill=Label))+
scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("BB" = "#00BFCa", "WZ" = 
"#F8766D"))+
geom_text(aes(label=round(Delay)), 
position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +   xlab("Travel 
Direction")+ ylab("Aggregated Delay (hours)") +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + theme(plot.title = 
element_text(size=12) )

ggplot(Data, aes(x=Direction, y=Delay)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label), 
outlier.colour = 8, outlier.shape = 1) + 
scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("BB" = "#00BFCa", "WZ" = 
"#F8766D")) +
xlab("Direction") + ylab("DElay") + ggtitle("By Direction") + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + theme(plot.title = 
element_text(size=12)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: If you don't mind installing another package it might be worth having a look at ggpattern

Comment: No problem with installing ggpattern package. Can you indicate on how it is done with ggpattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link can help you: https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-array.html#geom-map-pattern-

The function geom_bin2d_pattern() seems to be what you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).